# Proof using quadratic formula

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

> If $$M = {\begin{pmatrix}
>         a&b\\ 
>         c&d\\  
>         \end{pmatrix}}$$
>   Prove that if $\operatorname{tr}(M)^2 > 4\det(M)$, then $M$ is diagonalisable.

So the $\det(M)= ad - bc$ and the trace of $M$, $\operatorname{tr}(M)= a+d$.

Therefore, we should prove that $$ (a+d)^2 > 4(ad-bc) $$
Am I allowed to use the formula for quadratic polynomial, can I expess it like that: $$ a^2 -4(ad + bc) + d^2 $$ but what would that gain me? Could you please give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is$$(x-a)(x-d)-bc=x^2-(a+d)x+ad-bc.$$It has two distinct real roots if and only if$$(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)>0,$$that is, if and only if $\operatorname{tr}^2M>4\det M$.

Comment: So first I should evaluate the charpoly of M but how do the two distinct real roots relate to the square of tr(M) > 4det(M) ?

Comment: @Hello A polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ with real coefficients has $2$ real roots if and only if $b^2>4ac$.